# Probability problem : why is this wrong

Tags: probability

If you throw up 3 dice and want to calculate the probability of at least one six, my math book uses the complement rule as follows:

1- (5/6)^3

which is clear for me, but i tried it another way:

at least one six means either one, two, or three times a six, so i got this:

(3C1 * 15C2 + 3C2 * 15C1 + 3C3 )/ 18C3

So I noted there are 6 times 3, thus 18 elements with 3 dice. Picking 3 from 18 are all possible combinations. In the numerator I put the three possibilities, so one, two, or three times a 6.

But i compared the outcome and it wasnt equal to that of the book.

Can anyone explain why this is wrong?

Thanks in advance, also how can i write mathematical expressions on this site?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I don't know where the $18$ comes from.  There are $6^3$ possible outcomes when you throw three dice.

Comment: Can you please explain what $15C2$ means here? So is it possible I choose two numbers from the same dice and the last dice shows nothing?

Comment: i think this method im using is just wrong, isnt it?

Comment: it means picking 2 elements from 15

Comment: And how would you? Do you have $18$ numbers from which you can freely choose? Are you not restricted in choosing one number from each dice?

Comment: Indeed, you cant choose from 18 elements

Comment: For $15C2$ and $15C1$, what are the $15$ things you are picking from?

Comment: 15C2 means 15 over 2, i supposed they are the other numbers other than the three 6's .

Comment: For one thing, you fail to take into account the probability of getting a $6$ each time you throw a die.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$^{18}C_3$ or ${18 \choose 3}=816$ is not the number of equally likely ways of throwing $3$ dice.  Since each die can take six equally likely values, $6^3=216$ is.  Similarly with the rest of your calculation.

So the alternative calculation should be $$\frac{^3C_1\,5^2 + \, ^3C_2\,5   +  \,^3C_3}{6^3}$$
and this is the same as $1-\left(\frac 56\right)^3=\frac{91}{216}$

Comment: thank you very much, thats was a perfect explanation

Answer (score 1):

A correct approach if you want to avoid the complement is
$$\frac{\sum_{k=1}^3 \binom{3}{k}5^{3-k}}{6^3} = \frac{\binom{3}{1}5^2+\binom{3}{2}5^1+\binom{3}{3}5^0}{6^3} = \frac{91}{216}$$